# How to get UserId of facebook from Facebook profile Url ?Is there any API available

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-4, facebook-graph-api, c#-4.0

I need API which can provide me userid from facebook profile url.
Eg: https://www.facebook.com/bhupinder.rajput.786  This is my profile url but when I hit this (https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/bhupinder.singh.rajput) url in Graph API But I get error response

{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#803) Cannot query users by their user name (bhupinder.rajput.786)",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 803,
    "fbtrace_id": "ChRSh/G8Q0J"
  }
}

Then I try to scrap this url to get userid from Html source but when I hit this url I am getting response in Punjabi language.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URI);
            HttpWebResponse requestp = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(requestp.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
            SourceCode = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            SourceCode = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(SourceCode);
            requestp.Close();
```

Comment: Facebook forbids scraping via its TOS: https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php

Answer (score 0):

Since Graph API v2.0 (1.5 years ago!), it's no longer possible to use the `username` field and match this to the global Facebook user id.

Now, all apps have to use the app-scoped user id. If you'd use Facebook Login, this would be not a problem.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0